# Why do some tests not display in the NUnit Test Runner?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, integration, functional-testing

I don't know if "NUnit Test Runner" is the proper terminology, or "NUnit GUI" or what, but what I'm talking about is this:

[image]

I have half a dozen tests that should display below the "Integration\HHSClientIntegrationTests" portion but, as you can see, only two do, and I can't suss it out or grok it at all why some are chosen and others rejected by the testing harness.

Here is the test code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
. . .

namespace HHS.Web.Tests.IntegrationTest
{
    [TestFixture, Category(DBPPCOMMON.UnitTests.Categories.IntegrationTest)]
    public class HHSClientIntegrationTests
    {

        // This one displays in the test runner
        [Test]
        public void TestHHSInterface()
        {
            var HHSClient = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSClient>();

            var s = HHSClient.GetTestMessage("Sam (not Roger)", "Clemens");

            Assert.Greater(s.Value.Length, 0);
        }

        // This one displays in the test runner
        [Test]
        public void TestHHSDeliveryInterface()
        {
            var Delivery = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDelivery>();

            var i = Delivery.GetCount();

            Assert.Greater(i, 17); 
        }

    // The rest do NOT display in the NUnit test runner
    [Test]
    public void TestHHSDeliveryInvNumByIdInterface()
    {
        var Delivery = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDelivery>();

        var s = Delivery.GetDeliveryInvoiceNumberById(42);

        Assert.Greater(s.Length, 0);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestHHSDeliveryItemInterface()
    {
        var DeliveryItem = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDeliveryItem>();

        var i = DeliveryItem.GetCount();

        Assert.Greater(i, 42);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestHHSDeliveryItemInterfacePostPT109Data()
    {
        var DeliveryItem = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDeliveryItem>();

        Random rndm = new Random();
        int randomNum = rndm.Next(1000);
        var gwid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string dataPoints = String.Format("serNum{0};tx{0};siteNum{0};{1}.xml;PT109_user{0};tx_memo{1};file_beg{0};file_end{0}", randomNum, gwid);
        . . .
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }
```

The interfaces resolved (IHHSClient, IHHSDelivery, and IHHSDeliveryItem) look like this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public interface IHHSClient
    {
        HHSEntity GetTestMessage(String id1, String id2);
    }
}
```

...and this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public interface IHHSDelivery
    {
        int GetCount();
        Delivery GetById(int ID);
        String GetDeliveryInvoiceNumberById(int ID);
        IEnumerable<Delivery> GetRange(int ID, int CountToFetch);
        IEnumerable<Delivery> GetAll();
        Delivery Add(Delivery item);
        bool PostDelivery(int Id, string InvoiceNumber, decimal TotalAmount, string VendorID, string Site, string EditListOption, string RedemptionOption, bool AllowNewItems, string dbContext);
    }
}
```

...and this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public interface IHHSDeliveryItem
    {
        int GetCount();
        DeliveryItem GetById(int ID);
        IEnumerable<DeliveryItem> GetRange(int ID, int CountToFetch);
        IEnumerable<DeliveryItem> GetAll();
        DeliveryItem Add(DeliveryItem item);
        void InsertIntoPT109Data(string serialNum, string tx, string site_no, string xmlfile, string PT109_user, string tx_memo, string file_beg, string file_end);
        bool InsertIntoPT109Data(String stringifiedRecord);
    }
}
```

The classes that implement these interfaces look like this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public class RESTHHSClient : IHHSClient
    {
    . . .

        public HHSEntity GetTestMessage(String id1, String id2)
        {
            var res = RESTAPIClient.GET<HHSEntity>(null
               , new Uri(HHSClientSettings.HHSAPI)
               , String.Format("api/Test/{0}/{1}"
                                , id1
                                , id2)
                                );

            if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(res.message);
            }

            return res.result; 
        }

    }
}
```

...and this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public class RESTHHSDelivery : IHHSDelivery
    {
    . . .

        String IHHSDelivery.GetDeliveryInvoiceNumberById(int ID)
        {
            var res = RESTAPIClient.GET<String>(null
               , new Uri(HHSClientSettings.HHSAPI)
               , "api/delivery/invnumbyid"
               );

            if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(res.message);
            }

            return res.result;
        }

        int IHHSDelivery.GetCount()
        {
            var res = RESTAPIClient.GET<int>(0
               , new Uri(HHSClientSettings.HHSAPI)
               , "api/deliveries/Count"
               );

            if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(res.message);
            }

            return res.result;
        }
```

...and this:

```
namespace HHS.Client
{
    public class RESTHHSDeliveryItem : IHHSDeliveryItem
    {
    . . .

        public int GetCount()
        {
            var res = RESTAPIClient.GET<int>(0
               , new Uri(HHSClientSettings.HHSAPI)
               , "api/deliveryitems/Count"
               );

            if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(res.message);
            }

            return res.result;
        }

        public bool InsertIntoPT109Data(String stringifiedRecord)
        {
            bool success = true;
                var res = RESTAPIClient.POSTOBJECT_GETNOTHING<String>(null
                   , new Uri(HHSClientSettings.HHSAPI)
                   , "api/deliveryitems/InsertIntoPT109Data"
                   );

                if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
                {
                    success = false;
                    throw new Exception(res.message);
                }
            return success;
        }
    }
}
```

So what is different between the ones (the two, I should say) that display in the list of tests, and the others, that don't? I'm sure there's a logical explanation, but at this juncture, NUnit seems as capricious and inconsistent as a millionairess heiress with a Mexican Hairless.

### UPDATE

The local NUnit Whisperer looked at it, and it turned out that the Test project's "Command line arguments" value was wrong; we recently switched from TFS to Git, and that was still pointing at the old (TFS) project.

Now, with that val updated, all the tests display, and the one that should fail does.

Comment: Err, looks OK to me. Unless it's to do with indentation as those test are not indented properly, but that might just be a pasting issue...

Comment: You're joking, right (although, yes, the code didn't transfer its sartorial splendor as faithfully as one would hope)?

Comment: It was kind of tongue in cheek but from one test to the next, they're pretty identical. Perhaps something as silly as a clean/rebuild or restart of the dev env might help?

Comment: It's been the case for several days and even more builds, so I'm afraid it's not a build/restart "thang"

Comment: Is your test project set to build on a full build ? Try building it individually. Otherwise I'd start shifting things around to see what happens. For example, switch contents of working test with non working.

Comment: Okay, I did a Clean, then a Rebuild (which it said was a Rebuild All as it was chugging along), then a Build on just the test project; I don't know if all that was sensible or superstitious (I'm not really superstitious, but I am a *little bit* stitious sometimes); at any rate, it made no difference in what was displayed in the NUnit window/form.

Comment: Try shifting the code round then (grasping at straws now!)

Comment: Know you've checked this, but make sure you are pointing the GUI at the proper test assembly.  Could be an old version it is pointing at.

Comment: And also check you are building in debug mode as that's what NUnit is pointing at.

Comment: @dbugger: How do I verify that I am "pointing the GUI at the proper test assembly"?

Comment: @DavidG: How do I "check [I am] building in debug mode"?

Comment: You select the proper dll file in the GUI tool.  Beware similar but not identical paths, especially if you have older versions lying around.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon In Visual Studio, make sure the configuration is "Debug" and not "Release" or some other configuration you have in that solution.

Comment: Note that NUnit is pointing at your debug DLL, you can tell by looking at the screenshot, the 2nd line in the treeview ends with `\bin\Debug\...`

Comment: The local NUnit Whisperer looked at it, and it turned out that the Test project's "Command line arguments" value was wrong; we recently switched from TFS to Git, and that was still pointing at the old (TFS) project.

Now, with that val updated, all the tests display, and the one that should fail does.

Comment: Then I would recommend you delete the question, it holds no value for future visitors since it was a local unrelated problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Is it impossible that somebody else would have the same problem? I think not.